# How to write shell script to restart tomcat7 automatically using cron?

Tags: shell, tomcat, cron

I am very new to shell script,in my company i need restart all application servers in production at or before 12.30 pm everyday.can i automate this process by shell script also will it affect any other application running on the server.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

At last i found answer to restart tomcat automatically by writing a simple script and setting-up that script on cron whatever time sequence i need restart application server.

Script

#! /bin/sh
SERVICE=/etc/init.d/tomcat7

```
 $SERVICE restart
```

Cron job

30 12 * * *  /root/restarttomacat.sh

It wont affect any other applications.